# python lantz logging error

Tags: python, driver

First time Lantz user (http://lantz.readthedocs.org/) and I can't get through step 2 of the tutorial.

I believe that everything is installed correctly.

Here's the code I'm running, as found here
http://lantz.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial/using.html:

```
from lantz import LOGGER
from lantz.log import log_to_screen, DEBUG, INFO, CRITICAL
from lantz.drivers.examples import LantzSignalGenerator

# This directs the lantz logger to the console.
log_to_screen(DEBUG)

with LantzSignalGenerator('TCPIP::localhost::5678::SOCKET') as inst:
    print(inst.idn)
    print(inst.waveform)
```

and here's what I get back. It's actually this repeated a number of times for each logger output line...

```
--- Logging error ---
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Nick\Anaconda3\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 978, in emit
    msg = self.format(record)
  File "C:\Users\Nick\Anaconda3\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 828, in format
    return fmt.format(record)
  File "C:\Users\Nick\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\lantz\log.py", line 148, in color_format
    parts[0] = bef + self.colorize(dur, record) + aft
  File "C:\Users\Nick\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\lantz\log.py", line 136, in colorize
    return color + message + Style.RESET_ALL
NameError: name 'Style' is not defined
Call stack:
  File "test_fungen_logger.py", line 15, in <module>
    print(inst.idn)
  File "C:\Users\Nick\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\lantz\driver.py", line 355, in __exit__
    self.finalize()
  File "C:\Users\Nick\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\lantz\messagebased.py", line 332, in finalize
    super().finalize()
  File "C:\Users\Nick\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\lantz\action.py", line 129, in call
    instance.log_info('{} returned {}', name, out)
  File "C:\Users\Nick\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\lantz\driver.py", line 304, in log_info
    self.log(logging.INFO, msg, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Nick\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\lantz\driver.py", line 296, in log
    logger.log(level, msg, *args, extra=self.log_extra)
Message: '{} returned {}'
Arguments: ('finalize', None)
```

How should I go about troubleshooting this??
Running on win7, anaconda3 install

Answer (score 0):

I believe you already have an answer for that, but I've just got the same error and found out how to solve it from github [in this link](https://github.com/LabPy/lantz/issues/51)

In short, you should search for the file log.py inside the lantz folder (in my case it was in C:\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\lantz). Open the file and insert this just after "import threading" (line 19 for me):

> import colorama
>
> from colorama import Fore, Back, Style

This may fix this issue.